# Send mass emails with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to send mass emails using ASP.Net?

For example a site administrator needs to send email (e.g. a newsletter) to all of his site’s users.

What is the best way to do this with ASP.Net 3.5 and C#?

Answer (score 9):

Edit per Troy's comment.

You should use an external process to send the emails. If your email list grows to a few mere hundred you'll run into timeouts in no time. Once you get into the lists that are a thousand or a million records long you can forget about any workable solution using ASP.Net alone.

I've actually developed a windows service that handles sending out mass emails. Basically in ASP.Net I create a campaign and a batch job in various db records and then insert a list of recipients as well. Once the job has been fully written to the db it's status is changed so that the Windows Service knows it can come along and start processing the job. Then the ASP.Net site can look at the records at any time to determine how far along the service has gotten.

Comment: The key to this message is that there is a process for queuing and a separate process for sending. I've used the same approach (in perfectly legitimate circumstances!) and the insurance this gives against possible timeouts when enumerating a large number of recipients is invaluable.

Comment: +1 - I have taken this exact same approach. You have to have good error handling and recovery for the process to be robust, but it's a good strategy.

Comment: I would agree that an external service is MUCH preferred to coding it myself.

Comment: How about web-services? Is it a good approach for this situation?

Comment: Web services are still just web pages handled by the web server so you'll run into the same issue. They may be useful for abstracting some of the functionality away for use with other projects but ultimately you'll need to use a windows service if you want it to function correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If I were writing this on my own, I would simply get the email addresses from the database and loop through using the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class.

Please, however, ensure that you are aware of the CAN-SPAM act and that you follow the guidelines.

Comment: Speaking from experience this is a really poor approach.

Comment: I’ve tested it before, but don’t think about it if you want to send emails to more than 100 addresses!

Comment: @Spencer if you're going to voice a dissenting opinion, at least provide some details as to why you disagree with the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link >>>> [Sending Mass Email using ASP.Net](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2002112901&page=1)
The source is in VB.Net but since the MFCL is the same you can easily change the code in CSharp. However the aspx part remains the same.

Comment: Using BCC is a good approach but I don’t think that it is a good idea if you want to send email to more than 1000 addresses.

Comment: I'm going to vote this one up because from a performance standpoint, it's probably better than sending individual emails.  Also, using @BabakArj's comment, it would not be too hard to use a loop to build up a bcc list to a certain number of entries, then send that and contineue on with the rest.